# Windows Phone Dev. Adding items to Pan-Page doesn't work

Tags: forms, xaml, windows-phone, panoramas

I have

```
   <!--Panorama item one-->
   <controls:PanoramaItem Header="Search">

   </controls:PanoramaItem>
```

and what I simply want to do, is dropping some TextBoxes etc. into it.
But when I drop a Textbox (while the panorama item one-grid is selected), visual studio adds these form items outside the panorama pages, somewhere at the bottom of the XAML.

How can I add forms into the panorama item I decided them for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A grid. I needed to add a grid, to store all my elements inside.